# Return a value from a column if multiple criteria are met

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, google-sheets-filter

Can anyone teach me how I can return a value from a column if multiple criteria are met where if:

- a cell in a column of another sheet contains a word in a cell (referenced)
- the same row in another column contains `SUBMITTED`
- the same row in another column contains a text in a cell (referenced)

I tried doing this:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!AE2:AE="*"&B4&"*",Sheet1!G2:G="SUBMITTED",Sheet1!C2:C=D3),Sheet1!D2:D)
```

but this doesn't return a value. So, I tried using `INDEX` & `MATCH` using an array formula like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(Sheet1!D2:D,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!AE2:AE="*"&B4&"*")*(Sheet1!G2:G="SUBMITTED")*(Sheet1!C2:C=D3),0)))
```

but somehow this returns an error:

> Did not find value "1" in `MATCH` evaluation.

Am I doing something wrong with my `MATCH`? I'm not sure what's going on here.

And also would this be heavy if I were to do this to 10k cells? Would a script/using `QUERY` be better in returning these fields?

Comment: using `QUERY` is "heavier" solution. `ARRAYFORMULA` does not understand `AND` formula, therefore, every statement/criterion needs to be converted into 0/1 logic. `IF` formula does not understand `"*"` you need to use `FILTER` with `SEARCH` for that. to return cell found on the corresponding row you need to use `VLOOKUP`. `QUERY` won't return you cells on the corresponding rows - `QUERY` will bulk it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
 (IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!AE2:AE, 
  FILTER(Sheet1!AE2:AE, 
  SEARCH("*"&B4&"*", Sheet1!AE2:AE)), 1, 0), )<>"")*
 (Sheet1!G2:G="SUBMITTED")*
 (Sheet1!C2:C=D3), Sheet1!D2:D, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for this! is it possible that I return only 1 cell, and the first cell it matches only? because this formula returns the range, but only the matched cell pops up. but it still leaves a gaping hole in the data.

Comment: try: `=INDEX(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
 (IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!AE2:AE, 
  FILTER(Sheet1!AE2:AE, 
  SEARCH("*"&B4&"*", Sheet1!AE2:AE)), 1, 0), )<>"")*
 (Sheet1!G2:G="SUBMITTED")*
 (Sheet1!C2:C=D3), Sheet1!D2:D, )),"where Col1 is not null"),1,1)`

Comment: This worked beautifully. I'm guessing the QUERY is to clean the null values in the column, and INDEX is to only get the 1 value?

Comment: Somehow changing the `B4` doesn't change the value of the search. It returns the same previous cell. Would changing the index value capture the correct cell?

Comment: yes for query and yes for index. Index could. try to remove index and see how cells change and make sure you are after right first value